# In R, how to compute across conditional values in a for loop?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

testdataX contains several columns; SubNo for each subject, TopicNo (8 topics per subject, so each subject has 8 rows), Test2RT (reaction time), and Test2acc (accuracy). My end goal is get a reaction time measurement per subject, averaged across topics, and only for those topics for which the subject got the question right (i.e., Test2acc==1). I'm new to R, so this is what I've tried:

```
   for (i in subvecA) {
            TcorrtA[i] = mean(testdataX$Test2RT[testdataX$TopicNo==1 & testdataX$SubNo==i & 
    testdataX$Test2acc==1] + testdataX$Test2RT[testdataX$TopicNo==3 & testdataX$SubNo==i & 
    testdataX$Test2acc==1] + testdataX$Test2RT[testdataX$TopicNo==5 & testdataX$SubNo==i & 
    testdataX$Test2acc==1] + testdataX$Test2RT[testdataX$TopicNo==7 & testdataX$SubNo==i & 
testdataX$Test2acc==1])
        }
```

This looks about right; to my mind it is saying: for each subject in subvecA, get the mean of the test2RT for each topic for that person provided that the answer was correct.

I get an error message reading:

Error in TcorrtA[i] = testdataX$Test2RT[testdataX$TopicNo == 1 & testdataX$SubNo ==  : 
  replacement has length zero

As an initial debugging attempt, I plugged in one of the subject numbers for i and ran each line separately, e.g.:

```
testdataX$Test2RT[testdataX$TopicNo==7 & testdataX$SubNo==9 & testdataX$Test2acc==1]
```

Gives me the reaction time for that person for that trial, which that subject got correct.
But when I run a similar line where that subject got it incorrect, the output says: numeric(0). I suppose I was expecting NA or maybe FALSE, and figured it would disregard NA/FALSE when taking the mean, but neither of my suppositions were correct.

I feel like it can't run the operations across trials where some outputs provide numeric(0). How do I get around this problem?

Thanks for any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a minimal, working example for these questions.

```
set.seed(1618)
testdataX <- data.frame(SubNo = rep(1:10, each = 8), TopicNo = 1:8,
                        Test2ans = rbinom(80, 1, .5), Test2acc = rnorm(80))

# head(testdataX, 10)
#    SubNo TopicNo Test2ans   Test2acc
# 1      1       1        0  1.9079326
# 2      1       2        1  1.5649938
# 3      1       3        0 -1.5409056
# 4      1       4        0 -2.3135941
# 5      1       5        0 -1.0416061
# 6      1       6        1 -3.5043291
# 7      1       7        1 -0.7204609
# 8      1       8        0  0.3278730
# 9      2       1        0 -1.2320833
# 10     2       2        0 -1.3178366
```

The real answer would be to use a "more R" way of doing this. Any of the methods below or countless others from base R or third party packages would work.

```
by(df <- testdataX[testdataX$Test2ans == 1, ], df$SubNo, 
                  FUN = function(x) mean(x$Test2acc))
with(df, ave(Test2acc, SubNo, FUN = mean))
with(df, tapply(Test2acc, SubNo, mean))
aggregate(Test2acc ~ SubNo, data = df, FUN = mean)
```

As for a for loop, I might do it like this. The loop should be very logical, but I was trying to read your code, and it looked as if you were trying to do something completely different than what your explanation was.

You should be able to translate approximately what you want into a loop

```
## pre-allocate some memory (good practice to start)
TcorrtA <- numeric(length(unique(testdataX$SubNo)))
for (i in unique(testdataX$SubNo)) {
  ## take the mean of a subset of the data by subject number but only when 
  ## the test answer is 1, ie, correct answer
  ## and I only care about the Test2acc column
  ## then take the mean of that vector
  TcorrtA[i] = mean(testdataX[with(testdataX, SubNo == i & Test2ans == 1), 'Test2acc'])
}
TcorrtA
```

All the methods here give me this result:

```
# [1] -0.88659871 -0.44081851 -0.04615321  0.03587924 -0.66483847  0.34371615
# [7] -0.26312176 -0.36862050  0.59667122  0.49787479
```